Are questions about communities in video games on-topic?
I'm building a group of players in a (public) survival Minecraft server. Scrolling through the Community Building stack exchange, I noticed every question was related to websites or apps like social media.
Would asking a question about communities in video games be on-topic or is that better suited elsewhere?
Questions would be related to how to prevent griefing, implement some player-run 'law' system, etc. as we've recently encountered griefers joining the town and destroying things/killing pets. More details would be provided in the question(s) if it's considered on-topic.

Yes, questions about communities in video games should be on-topic.
